# How do I use ImageMagick binaries from PHP? 

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am using locally the ImageMagick library for image editing. In my online shared server there was no ImageMagick installed but after requested, they installed ImageMagick binaries at `/usr/local/bin`, e.g. the `convert` binary at `/usr/local/bin/convert`.

How can I use those binaries in my script?

Comment: Those are regular executables.  You'd have to use `exec(...)` calls to invoke them. Ask if they'll install the PHP imagick PECL module for you, which talks to the imagick libraries directly instead of using external programs.

Comment: Please clarify: are you writing a perl or PHP script?

Comment: Edited the question to removed mentioning of Perl, this has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use exec like

```
$inputFile = 'file.jpg';
$outputFile = 'file.png';
exec('/usr/local/bin/convert '.$inputFile.' '.$outputFile);
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Download and install ImageMagick on your local machine.
2. Create a test folder with an image or two to play with.
3. Open up the shell, go to the test folder, and start playing with the commands until you find a command that gets you the desired results. Consult with the (not-so-helpful) documentation: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php
4. Paste this command into your php script, replacing any filenames or arguments with php variables as needed.
5. exec(  *// command* );

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't "perl binaries", they're the C libraries and binary executables.

You need to build/install the php module that uses them.

Comment: It is a shared server. I can't do that

Comment: Then they need to. The other option is building them yourself with an install path to your home directory. You would just include from there in your php script. Option C is what someone mentioned above, using `exec()` from your php script to call the compiled executables in /usr/local/bin

Comment: To tell you truth, those are C executables

Comment: The original question was different. And if he wants to use the PHP module, he's using the shared libraries (which are also used by the binary executables ;) ).

Comment: Do you ask anyone who upvoting your answer for their reason too?