# Divide photo to X and Y pieces

Tags: php, image, fatal-error, imagick

I have a 96x96 image and i need to divide it in 36 pieces of 16x16 and i have a script given below works fine on my localhost but not working on my webhost.

```
    function makeTiles($name, $imageFileName, $crop_width, $crop_height)
    {
    $dir = "/pic";
    $slicesDir = "/pic/16X16";

    // might be good to check if $slicesDir exists etc if not create it.
    $ImgExt = split(".",$imageFileName);
    $inputFile = $dir . $imageFileName;

    $img = new Imagick($inputFile);
    $imgHeight = $img->getImageHeight();
    $imgWidth = $img->getImageWidth();

    $cropWidthTimes = ceil($imgWidth/$crop_width);
    $cropHeightTimes = ceil($imgHeight/$crop_height);
    for($i = 0; $i < $cropWidthTimes; $i++)
    {
        for($j = 0; $j < $cropHeightTimes; $j++)
        {
            $img = new Imagick($inputFile);
            $x = ($i * $crop_width);
            $y = ($j * $crop_height);
            $img->cropImage($crop_width, $crop_height, $x, $y);
            $data = $img->getImageBlob();
            $newFileName = $slicesDir . $name . "_" . $x . "_" . $y . ".".$ImgExt[1];
            $result = file_put_contents ($newFileName, $data);
        }
    }
}
```

Getting fatal error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in myfile.php line number
```

My host saying:

> Imagick and image magic both are same unfortunately, we do not have
>   them as a PHP module we have binaries like ImageMagick binary and
>   Image magic path is /usr/local/bin. Include this function in your
>   script and check the website functionality from your end.

I dont know how to fix this error.

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe an include statement with the path the the Imagick class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you will have to invoke the `imagick` binary from your script using `exec()`:

```
 exec('/usr/local/bin/convert '.$inputFile.' -crop 96x96+ox+oy '.$newFilename);
```

The `ox` and `oy` should be replaced with the correct offset values.

Here is are a couple of links that might help:

1. [How do I use Imagick binaries from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277601/how-do-i-use-imagemagick-binaries-from-php)
2. [Imagick - Convert Command-line tool](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)

Comment: Now my host saying `It is not possible to run the script on our servers` :( is there any other way do divide image in pieces without `imagic`

Comment: Yes of course there is, you could simply use standard GD functions like `imagecreatefromjpg()`, `imagecopy()` and so on. Check out the GD and image functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

Comment: You should try talking to you hosting provider, asking them how to use `imagick` from your php script. The first message seems to suggest that it should actually work.

Comment: Getting this error when i try above given code. 

`$inputFile = '2_thumb.jpg';   `
`$newFilename = '2_thumb16.jpg';   `
`exec('/usr/local/bin/convert '.$inputFile.' -crop 96x96+16+16 '.$newFilename);   `

`The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.
The script had an error or it did not produce any output. If there was an error, you should be able to see it in the error log.`